# Location of the mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Currently I am learning MySql using commandline in ubuntu and made a backup of my database named 'sandwich' using mysqldump command.

**mysql> #mysqldump -u root -p123456 sandwich > db_backup.sql;**

Where I can find this 'db_backup.sql' file on the disk. Please tell me a specific file path where i can find this file.

Comment: in your current directory pwd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you were when you executed the command - db_backup.sql will be found there as you didn't specify a full path.

Try your home dir or the web dir if you can't remember - anywhere you might have been when entering mysql. If all else fails you can use find:

```
find / -name 'db_backup.sql'
```

this may take some time so if you can narrow down the area of search and replace / with ~/ for example, that would help.

Comment: yeah.I got the file. It's in my current directory in which I was working.Thanks.

Comment: You can learn your current directory with `pwd` and get your backup there. so before or after the dump check your directory

Answer (score 0):

run following command without logging into mysql terminal.

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name > db_dump.sql
```

It will ask for password. Enter password.

When dump is complete type following command.

```
ls
```

You will see `db_dump.sql` file in the list.